# Why does dask return a subgraph rather than a computation on read_csv().compute()?

Tags: dask

When I do `dd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')`, it correctly identifies the structure:

```py
In [13]: dd.read_csv('AAPL.csv')
Out[13]:
Dask DataFrame Structure:
              2016-01-04T09:00:00Z   105.45 105.45.1    103.6  103.6.1    17462
npartitions=1
                            object  float64  float64  float64  float64  float64
                               ...      ...      ...      ...      ...      ...
Dask Name: read-csv, 1 tasks
```

But when I try to actually compute it, it always returns this:

```py
In [14]: dd.read_csv('AAPL.csv').compute()
Out[14]: 
0    (<Serialize: subgraph_callable-f9057ef2-07c7-4...
dtype: object
```

It works fine when importing with pandas. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: That doesn't happen to me. what version of dask are you using? Also, [please don't post images of code or results](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: also - if you suspect the issue is with the structure of your CSV, can you help us out with a repeatable example?

Comment: Unrelated, but the column names look like the header is missing (maybe something like `time, open, high, low, close, volume`).